# Data View Web Part pointing at multiple XML feeds/internal SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part, content-query-web-part, xslt

I am trying to put together a web part with a mixture of jQuery display functionality on a DataView web part.

The idea is to have multiple sources of news feeds from both an internal SharePoint list and a few different external news sites. This would all be displayed in a web part with a slider sorting functionality to choose between which news feed to display, similar to

[jQuery Sliding Tabs](http://codecanyon.net/item/sliding-tabs-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/141774?ref=1stwebdesigner)

I have not used a DVWP (Data View web part) before and I'm unsure how to tackle this. Would it be possible do you think to add connections to the separate feeds in the data view control settings in SPD and edit the results into the required format with the XSL when I have the XML returned? I had originally done this as a CQWP, but I wasn't thinking ahead at all to the XML feeds.

I am tagging this with SPD too, as I think you have to work with SPD in order to customise the data view web part, but I could be wrong.

Any pointers would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a blog article on how to do this a different way: Hopefully I should just be able to customise the list filter web part with XSL and attach it to an RSS web part:

[John W Powell: Make the RSS Feed Viewer Web Part Dynamic Using Filters and Web Part Connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnwpowell/archive/2009/03/01/bind-the-rss-feed-viewer-to-multiple-feeds-using-filters-and-web-part-connections.aspx)

Thanks to Emir Liu who had the same idea here:

[TechNet: Custom chrome type with custom web part editing options possible?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/2e3e77fe-e301-4da6-8d04-5bc8b41b8d4f/#9f167394-024b-4d1f-8361-b6b15c431c10)